# database design for movies showtimes

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm

I have showtimes table for movies & cinemas in database and I need to make option to edit showtime for next week without publish it.. what's the best solution ? create another table ?

my database:
[image]

Comment: What's the structure of your tables?

Comment: Sounds like another column might already do the job? Anyway, this is impossible to answer without more detail. What is your table doing exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if you want to save old values** (before updating), It's better to use another table, but **if you don't want to do so and you don't need to store old values**, it's better to use a flag 'published' (new column in the table), and when any one update the values, set the 'published' flag to zero, then the admin should check it to set the 'published' flag to '1'. In user page only show records with published=1.

Comment: Good solution but you know I not need old data i need to delete all show times.. so in my table i need to store this week and next week what's the best ?

Comment: if I understand what you say correctly, you don't want to store old data, so the best solution is to use 'published' flag.